# multiple conditions in .htaccess redirect with both if and or

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, if-statement

Im trying to setup htaccess to redirect from "domain.com" to "www.domain.com" if request is not "t.domain.com"

Below takes care of the first part:

```
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^$
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS}s ^on(s)|
    RewriteRule ^ http%1://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

But how do I extend this to not do a redirect if the request is "t.domain.com"?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(www|t)\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS}s ^on(s)|
RewriteRule ^ http%1://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Thanks. This seems to work with t.domain.com but with t.domain.com/whatever it still redirects to www.t.domain.com/whater ...

Comment: No it will skip all `t.domain.com` requests. Make sure you test in a new browser. `%{HTTP_HOST}` variable remains same irrespective of what URL you use starting with `t.domain.com`.